# Как сделать флексбокс со скроллом?

Tags: html, css, sass, scss

Проблема такая , я подгружаю  изображение в флексбокс, бооковая панель с коментами выглядит нормально,но как только слишком много комментов, контейнер начинает растягиваться, из за этого флекс элемента Comments,а мне нужно , нужно, чтобы высота окошка не менялась, а в случае переполнения появлялся скролл у комментов, никак не пойму, как это организовать. Например, если изображение будет длиннее , то и правая часть тоже будет длиннее , но никак она не должна увеличивать все окно

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.DetailedPostBack{

  position: fixed;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  z-index: 3;
  .BlackScreen{
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;

  }
    .DetailedPost{
      position: relative;
      z-index: 4;
      max-width: 935px;
      width: 100%;
      min-height: 450px;
      background-color: black;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: stretch;
      img{
        flex: 1;
      }
      .DetailSecond{
        max-width: 335px;
        background-color: white;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;

          .PostHeader{
            display: flex;
            padding: 16px;
            height: 72px;
            align-items: center;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #efefef;
            img{
              width: 32px;
              height: 32px;
              border-radius: 50%;
            }
          }
        .CommentsSocial{
          width: 100%;
          display: flex;
          flex-direction: column;
          flex: 1;

          .Comments{
            word-break: break-word;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            flex: 1 1 auto;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            padding: 12px 16px;
            overflow-y: auto;

            img{
              width: 32px;
              height: 32px;
              border-radius: 50%;
            }
            .Comment{
              box-sizing: border-box;
              max-width: 335px;
              width: 100%;
              display: flex;
              margin-bottom: 16px;
              word-wrap: break-word;
              .CommentText{
                flex:1;
                  margin-left: 18px;
                font-size: 0.9rem;

                h2{
                  display: inline-block;
                  margin:0;
                }
              }
            }
          }
          .Social{
            border-top: 1px solid #efefef;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #efefef;
            margin-top: 4px;
            padding: 12px 16px;
            img{
              width: 28px;
              height: 28px;
              margin-right: 16px;
            }

          }
          .SendComment{
            padding: 8px;
            form{
              display: flex;
              input{
                flex: 1;
                border: none;
                background-color: white;
                padding: 4px;
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: `max-height, overflow: auto`?

Comment: @meine я бы поставил max-height, но я не знаю, какое это значение , ибо этот блок может меняться в длине в зависимости от картинки

Comment: @fake364 ты бы скинул код а то это пук в лужу